# Prevent the macro break for pass-protected self-destructing file

Tags: excel, vba, break

I've decided to create a pass-protected file which will self-destruct after three wrong password entries. The macro runs with the file open (UserForm with pass entry field pops up) but the weak point is that Ctrl-Break allows to stop the macro and get access to the code.

Is there any way to disable/prevent Break option in a particular workbook (via VBA, preferably)?

If you are interested, I can provide the macro upon request.

UPD: Here's the macro i'm using (Date based).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Date > Cdate("30/03/2015") Then
        WARNING.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

This part of code is assigned to "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons of the UserForm "WARNING".

```
Public i As Integer
Public b As Integer

Sub setib()
    i = 2 - b
    b = b + 0
End Sub

Private Sub CnclBtn_Click()
    WARNING.Hide
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Saved = True
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub OKBtn_Click()
    Call setib

    Dim Pass As String: Pass = "*your pass*"
    Dim PassInput As String: PassInput = WARNING.PassField.Text

    If PassInput = Pass Then
        MsgBox "Password is correct"
        GoTo Safe:
    Else
        If b < 2 Then
            MsgBox "Password is incorrect. " & i & " attempts left."
        Else
            MsgBox "No More attempts"
        End If
        If b = 2 Then
            WARNING.Hide
            GoTo Destroy:
        Else
            WARNING.PassField.Value = vbNullString
            WARNING.PassField.SetFocus
            b = b + 1
            GoTo EndSub:
        End If
    End If

Safe:
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, _
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.CountOfLines
    WARNING.Hide
GoTo EndSub:

Destroy:
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Saved = True
        .ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
        Kill .FullName
        .Close False
    End With

EndSub:
    Sheet1.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Please try `Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled`

Comment: Hi user3964075! Thank you for your reply! Will try as u suggested and come back to you with the result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply password-protect the VBA project. That will avoid the need to worry about playing with the `Application`-level settings for `EnableCancelKey`.

While the user may be able to "break" with the cancel key, they will not be able to view the code without supplying the proper password for the VBA project.

With the VBAProject *protected*, the user can "break" execution of the code, the user should not be able to enter "break mode", and the Excel application will not be interactive (so the user will *not* be able to access the worksheets).  At this point, the User Form will be frozen on the screen and the application unresponsive.  The user then has two options that I can see:

1. If they know the *name* of the userform, they could conceivably `Unload UserForm1` from the Immediate window in the VBE. So, you should pick some name for the UserForm which they will not likely guess.  If they do this, they will be able to access the file itself, but if you give the UF a secure name, they'll never guess it correctly.
2. Otherwise, they're SOL, unless they <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>, and kill the Excel application procdess.

**NOTE:** Excel passwords, whether on the worksheets or the VBAProject (or both) can be cracked by anyone intent on doing so, and are only a good measure to prevent inadvertent corruption or manipulation of the data.

Comment: Hi David Zemens! Thanks for your suggestion, but i think that the EnableCancelKey might be a better option, because i didn't hide the spreadsheets with data and want to restrict the access to it if the password is not entered. As i know, if the userform will be opened, it will not be possible to switch from it to spreadshees.

Comment: The cancel key option is dangerous, though...  There are other ways to do this. What behavior are you actually trying to prevent?

Comment: I've updated the original post with the code i'm using. So lets say that i have an excel database, for which i want to restrict the access after a certain date, and the only way to have that access is to enter the right password. To prevent password guessing/bruteforcing, the user will have only 3 attempts, after which the file will be removed completely. If the password is correct, the macro will clear itself and the file will become accessible. I do believe that password-protecting the macro is essential, as you mentioned, and will do it after i finalise the code.

Comment: I can break any  password protected Excel file in ONE attempt.  So can anyone with access to google and a hex editor like Notepad++.

Comment: If you're really trying to make the application "secure", then Excel passwords will never be a good solution to that. If you're simply trying to prevent the average user from breaking the file, or messing up the data, etc., then passwords will work. But they will not prevent a savvy user from accessing the file or the VBProject.

Comment: That sounds pretty awsome, any chance you can share that knowledge? :) Regarding the level of the user's knowledge - most probably it will be less than/average. For sure no hacking skills or anything like that :)

Comment: It's readily available on Google. As a matter of ettiquette (I believe it is frowned upon here), I don't share this on Stack Overflow, other than to warn people against thinking that an Excel "passwords" is a legitimate security measure, because it's not.

Comment: Found it. Really interesting approach, will try it out. Re the original issue, will try it out with pass-protected VBA. Need to rebuild the file again, because it self-destructed in the process of testing (forgot that i was working with the original file, not the copy). Luckily i've saved the code in Evernote ^____^